# Magento Enterprise Nofrills Layouts 1.10.1.1 compatibility

Tags: layout, magento

I just bought Alan Storm's new ebook, No Frills Magento Layouts, and completed all the exercises in chapters 1 and 2, but when I got to chapter 3, I was able to get the blank page  by changing the 'current package name' and 'layout' in the admin panel, but after copying app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/page.xml to app/design/frontend/default/nofrills_layoutbook/layout/page.xml i was unable to get the page to render as in figure 3.3 on page 60.  when viewing the listed url I still got the 'handles generated...' output as in the previous figure and without the modified layout, just a white background.  I noticed that some other blocks are being rendered.  Here is the entire output on the to the screen with path hints and block hints turned on:

```
Handles Generated For This Request:
default
STORE_default
THEME_frontend_default_nofrills_layoutbook
nofrills_booklayout_package_index
customer_logged_out
frontend/base/default/template/page/3columns.phtml
Mage_Page_Block_Html
frontend/base/default/template/page/html/head.phtml
Mage_Page_Block_Html_Head
frontend/base/default/template/page/js/cookie.phtml
Mage_Page_Block_Js_Cookie
frontend/base/default/template/page/html/notices.phtml
Mage_Page_Block_Html_Notices
frontend/base/default/template/page/html/header.phtml
Mage_Page_Block_Html_Header
Magento CommerceMagento Commerce

Default welcome msg!
frontend/base/default/template/page/template/links.phtml
Mage_Page_Block_Template_Links
frontend/base/default/template/page/switch/languages.phtml
Mage_Page_Block_Switch
frontend/base/default/template/page/html/breadcrumbs.phtml
Mage_Page_Block_Html_Breadcrumbs
frontend/base/default/template/page/html/footer.phtml
Mage_Page_Block_Html_Footer
frontend/base/default/template/page/switch/stores.phtml
Mage_Page_Block_Switch
frontend/base/default/template/page/template/links.phtml
Mage_Page_Block_Template_Links

Help Us to Keep Magento Healthy - Report All Bugs (ver. 1.10.1.1)
© 2009 Magento Enterprise Edition Demo Store. All Rights Reserved.
```

I'm running Enterprise 1.10.1.1 if you couldn't tell.  Every other example in the book has worked flawlessly, but I'm wondering if there's a compatibility issue with this version considering that the url in figure 3.3 is 'magento1point4.2.dev/nofrills_booklayout/package/index'.  Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: also, i tested this with 2 separate clean installs and got the same result

Comment: I don't have access to a 1.10.1.1 install at the moment, get in touch via email and I may be able to help http://alanstorm.com/contact

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking at older copies of Enterprise that I do have installed and it looks like (As part of the installation process), Magento sets the default theme to `enterprise`

```
System -> Configuration -> Design -> Default
```

So, anywhere the books says default/default, try substituting default/enterprise. Alternately, try removing the `enterprise` value from the admin to restore default not-configured system behavior.